# Why can't we connect to firestore on node.js server using just public apiKey

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In my React project, I am using firebase public apiKeys to access services like authentication and firestore. So it means we are not required to use `admin-sdk`.

Then why we need admin-sdk to leverage firebase services on server environments like node.js? Won't public apiKeys do just fine?

I mean client side is exposed to public while servers can be accessed by only the managers and developers of the organization.

Please explain me the reason for this.

Thank You!

Comment: @ShriHari please elaborate a bit more what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client-side SDK's can access resources like Firestore, Storage, etc, but the requests to these services need to pass the Security Rules.

The Admin SDK bypasses the security rules - and hence the Admin SDK needs to be run in a secure environment.

To answer your specific query though - you can use the Javascript Client SDK on a Node.js environment - but you have to keep in mind that the requests will be subject to the security rules you define for your Firebase resources. If you use the Admin SDK, your requests will bypass the security rules.